# ¿No funciona WebCam al instalar aplicación WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una aplicación WPF en C#,tengo un módulo para tomar fotografías a través de una Webcam, utilizo WebCam_Capture.dll y funciona a la perfección en modo local, al crear el setup incluyo todas las librerías necesarias para el funcionamiento, pero al instalarse en un cliente no funciona la cámara web. Manda referencia el siguiente mensaje referencia no establecida como instancia de un objeto ¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?

Comment: Sip. Pone mas controles en tu programa, porque no la esta encontrando por algun motivo.

Comment: He copiado la carpeta Debug a la máquila local y tampoco logra reconocer la cámara, mismo problema.